# overlay (or play an )video over an image as background - using gstreamer

Tags: cmd, gstreamer

I am working on a project where I need to display a video with "alpha keying" a region of interest based on color  and run it over an image so the image under the region of interest is visible over the video.

```
$ gst-launch-0.10 -e \
    videomixer name=mix\
    ! ffmpegcolorspace \
    ! xvimagesink \
    videotestsrc pattern=0 \
    ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=1/1, width=350, height=250 \
    ! textoverlay font-desc="Sans 24" text="CAM1" valign=top halign=left shaded-background=true \
    ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-200 left=-50 \
    ! mix.
     multifilesrc location="drawing_total_mask_1.jpg" caps="image/jpeg,framerate=1/1"
    ! jpegdec \
    ! textoverlay font-desc="Sans 26" text="Live from Pl" halign=left shaded-background=true auto-resize=false \
    ! ffmpegcolorspace \
    ! video/x-raw-yuv,format=\(fourcc\)AYUV \
    ! mix.
```

Searching for it I found something like this which allows me to display the test video (`videotestsrc`) over the image but when I give an alternate video source it wont do that .

The code I used to give my own source and the errors followed by it.

```
$ gst-launch-0.10 -e videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink    filesrc location = "asd.mp4" ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=1/1, width=350, height=250 !      textoverlay font-desc="Sans 24" text="CAM1" valign=top halign=left shaded-background=true !      videobox border-alpha=0 top=-200 left=-50 ! mix.   multifilesrc location=drawing_total_mask_1.jpg" caps="image/jpeg,framerate=1/1" ! jpegdec !      textoverlay font-desc="Sans 26" text="Live from Pl" halign=left shaded-background=true auto-resize=false !      ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv,format=\(fourcc\)AYUV ! mix.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTextOverlay:textoverlay0: Could not multiplex stream.
Additional debug info:
gsttextoverlay.c(1848): gst_text_overlay_video_event (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTextOverlay:textoverlay0:
received non-TIME newsegment event on video input
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTextOverlay:textoverlay1: Could not multiplex stream.
Additional debug info:
gsttextoverlay.c(1848): gst_text_overlay_video_event (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTextOverlay:textoverlay1:
received non-TIME newsegment event on video input
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter1: Filter caps do not completely specify the output format
Additional debug info:
gstcapsfilter.c(393): gst_capsfilter_prepare_buf (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter1:
Output caps are unfixed: video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)350, height=(int)250, format=(fourcc){ AYUV, YUY2, Y444, UYVY, Y42B, YV12, I420, Y41B }
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
```

I am not able find what's right I am not doing to make it work.

So to summarize
I want a video sourced by me  with an transparent alpha region, which when run on a image will display the image over the alpha region of interest in video.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out a way to do what I have asked in the question .I am posting it here for those whom it will help .

This will run video on top of an image. 
Note: If the video has any "orange" colored region , it will apply alpha keying transparency and the image will below will be displayed on tranparent region.cheers

```
gst-launch videomixer name=mix sink_0::alpha=1.0 sink_0::zorder=1 sink_1::zorder=2 
! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink filesrc location =vidoe.avi ! decodebin 
! alpha method=custom target-r=245 target-g=161 target-b=11 angle=10  
! ffmpegcolorspace ! mix.sink_1 multifilesrc location="image.jpg"
    caps="image/jpeg,framerate=1/1" 
! jpegdec 
! textoverlay font-desc="Sans 26" text="Live from Pl" halign=left 
    shaded-background=true auto-resize=false 
! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv,format=\(fourcc\)AYUV ! mix.sink_0
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to demultiplex and decode your video-file in order to be able to use it. just using `filesrc ! video/x-raw-yuv` will not magically extract the video data from an mp4. try something like `h264parse ! ffdec_h264` (in case your mp4 holds `h.264`  encoded data)

Comment: Can you please help me by putting what you said, in any pipeline  as example or use the one above. Thanks